# CSS formatting for IE 10 and IE 11

Tags: html, css

I'm having two issues.
My application is not centered in IE, but looks perfect in chrome.

1. I have conditional just for IE, but it doesn't seem to be working. The #outline is not shifting to the left like the ie.css file is telling it to.
2. It is my understanding that the conditional I put in the  isn't supported for IE 10 or IE 11 so  what can I do so that these versions aren't ignored?

The conditional I put in

```
  <!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

You can view it in action with all the files and whatnot here: http://andrewhnovak.com/AMC%20Ticket%20Calculator%202.0/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `zoom: 80%' from`amc.css` line 7. That is an IE only style, and is what is messing things up.

If you were trying to accomplish something by having that there, then let me know in the comments and I'll see if I can help. But you'll notice that that shrinkage isn't happening in any other browser.

Comment: It is now working. Removing the zoom: 80% fix the centering problem, but I do have an issue with the shrinkage. I have two monitors running at 1080p, but the webpage doesn't right on both screens. Here's a pic to show you what I mean. http://postimg.org/image/sm9108g2p/  Any suggestions?

Comment: So, same computer, same resolution for each monitor?

Comment: Correct. It's the same computer using a dual monitor. Both computers are running at 1080p as well.

Comment: 1080p just means high definition. It has nothing to do with the resolution, which would be something like 1024x768, or 1600x1200. Check what your resolutions are set to.

Comment: I can't say I fully understand you, but both monitors are set at 1920 x 1080p

Comment: Okay, that's a resolution now. Is that the default resolution for both monitors?